# Не убираются отступы

Tags: html, css

Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть небольшая разметка. Есть тег footer и есть к нему стили. Чтобы footer был закреплен на месте снизу и при скролигне оставался на месте, я дал ему свойство `position sticky` и `bottom: 0`. Однако, с каждой стороны, у меня появляются небольшие отсупы, а `margin` здесь не работает. Как это можно поправить? Спасибо

css

```
.footer{
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
width: 0;
height: 75px;
border-top: 1px solid;
backgroung-color: gray;
margin: 0
}
```

css

```
<footer class = "footer">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы убрали `margin` у `body`, то в таком случае, никаких отступов нет:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.example {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">example</div>
<div class="example">example</div>
<div class="example">example</div>
<div class="example">example</div>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

Comment: спасибо, я не обнулил сначала...

Comment: @Halland да не за что). Можете отметить ответ верным, если я вам помог?